# Dynamically add a chart component to a Razor Page

Tags: c#, chart.js, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazorise

I have build a nice chart (serverside) component with blazor. It uses jschart. Everything is fine, and it works great.

Inside the ChartComponent. I have this.

```
@using Blazorise.Charts
<Div Style=@($"position: relative; height:{ViewHeight}vh; width:{ViewWidth}vw;")>
    <LineChart @ref="lineChart" TItem="double" Clicked="@OnClicked"  Options="@chartOptions"/>
</Div>
```

(note the **lineChart** reference) and in the Razor.cs file I have defined a lineChart variable as well (used as Ref in Razor Page)

```
 LineChart<double> lineChart;
```

The problem is when I place it on a page without the foreach everything works fine.

```
<ChartComponent ViewHeight=50 ViewWidth=80 ColorScheme="Classic20" Multiple=true Items=@items></ChartComponent>
```

But now I want to add multiple of those components to the page.

```
@foreach (string graphSelector in datasets)
{
     <ChartComponent ViewHeight=50 ViewWidth=80 ColorScheme="Classic20" Multiple=true Items=@(items.Where(p => p.CounterInstance == graphSelector).ToList())></ChartComponent>
}
```

But when I put it inside a foreach I get an error stating lineChart is null...
I have tried several things but my guess is I am missing something.

inside the chartcomponent I do

```
await lineChart.Clear();
```

which gives me a

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Tried several things but don't know how to solve it.

I tried the solution proposed by MetinYakar.NET but I still get the same result.

[image: DebugView]

The chartcomponent is not null but some variables inside the chart component are.

Seems like when the component is on the page during the first render it wil work, but when it's not on the page during the first render the component is not properly initialized, a render of the chart itself willl fail.

I have the following code inside the ChartComponent.

```
        private async Task DataSetToChartSeries()
        {
            // Create a list of date labels
            string[] dateLabels = Items.Select(x => x.TimeRun.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")).Distinct().ToArray();
            await lineChart.Clear();
            await lineChart.AddLabels(dateLabels);
            if (Multiple == true)
            {
                List<string> datasets = Items.Select(p => p.CounterInstance).Distinct().ToList();
                foreach (string graphSelector in datasets)
                {
                    List<QueryResult> graphDataSet = Items.Where(p => p.CounterInstance == graphSelector).ToList();
                    await lineChart.AddDataSet(GetLineChartDataset(graphDataSet));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await lineChart.AddDataSet(GetLineChartDataset(Items));
            }
            await lineChart.Update(); <-- This line causes the error
        }
```

Also i have this in the razor file:

```
   @* Does not work*@
@*    @foreach (string key in chartSeries.Keys)
    {
        <ChartComponent ViewHeight=20 ViewWidth=80 ColorScheme="Classic20"  Multiple=true Items=@(GetChartSeries(key))></ChartComponent>
    }*@
    @*This does work but is not dynamic*@
    <ChartComponent ViewHeight=20 ViewWidth=80 ColorScheme="Classic20"  Multiple=true Items=@(GetChartSeries("Error"))></ChartComponent>
    <ChartComponent ViewHeight=20 ViewWidth=80 ColorScheme="Classic20"  Multiple=true Items=@(GetChartSeries("Information"))></ChartComponent>
    <ChartComponent ViewHeight=20 ViewWidth=80 ColorScheme="Classic20"  Multiple=true Items=@(GetChartSeries("Warning"))></ChartComponent>
```

The problem has something to do with the chart not beeing there when the item is first rendered.

Comment: Try to eliminate causes, put 2 charts on the page, with valid data on the first render. No foreach().

Comment: Exactly where are you calling `await lineChart.Clear();`?  You need to show more `ChartComponent` code for us to see what's going on!

Comment: Thanks guys i really appreciate your help. Added some code to show what works and what doesn't work...  If the component is there on the first render everything works as expected. But i i try to add the chartcomponent after the data is loaded it fails.

Comment: @Patrick - I should have been more explicit - which event in the component calls `DataSetToChartSeries` -`OnInitilaized{Async}`,.. ?  You've also appear to have changed  which line gives the error.  You initially said the `.Clear` line, but your additional code suggests `.Update`.  If it's the latter then `lineChart` can't be null as you have carried out operations on it further up the method.

Comment: Yes MRC, i know it's not null, you can see that in the debug screenshot, I can add the datasets but as soon as I update the chart I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys thanks for helping me.

I took the advice from Henk, and started from scratch with the codebase from The Blazorise Chart Example. I wrapped that like I did with my own component and to my surpise I could add multiple of those to my page.

After a lot of tracing and trying the most important change is that I moved the initialization of the chart to OnAfterRenderAsync.

```
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync( bool firstRender )
    {
        if ( firstRender )
        {
            await DataSetToChartSeries();
        }
    }
```

This made all the difference

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a property value in blazor project and add first declaration. Ex;

```
LineChart<double> lineChart { get; set; } = new LineChart<double>();
```

And check null for show in the view

```
@if(datasets?.Count > 0){
    @foreach (string graphSelector in datasets)
    {
         <ChartComponent ViewHeight=50 ViewWidth=80 ColorScheme="Classic20" Multiple=true Items=@(items.Where(p => p.CounterInstance == graphSelector).ToList())></ChartComponent>
    }
 } else {
    <b>datasets object null or empty</b>
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me, tried your solution but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

`Items=@(items.Where(p => p.CounterInstance == graphSelector)` looks a little suspicious to me.  Is `CounterInstance` a string, and what is in the string `graphSelector`?  I don't think ANY of that sounds like it should be a string at all.

You complained that

```
@foreach (string graphSelector in datasets)
{
     <ChartComponent ViewHeight=50 ViewWidth=80 ColorScheme="Classic20" Multiple=true Items=@(items.Where(p => p.CounterInstance == graphSelector).ToList())></ChartComponent>
}
```

gives an error that `lineChart` is `null`, but there's nothing like that in the `<ChartComponent>`

Comment: It's a variable inside chart component representing a line chart